# Login is not working in flutter with REST API

Tags: flutter

Hi in the below code when I enter my mobile number, password and then click on the login button nothing is happening. My API working in Postman is not working here.

When I press the button it is not working, Entering a valid mobile number and password are not working.

Can anyone help me to find where I did any mistakes?

Login_screen.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sample_live/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:sample_live/model/login_model.dart';
import 'package:sample_live/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:sample_live/login_otp.dart';

import 'ProgressHUD.dart';
import 'api/api_service.dart';



class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String name;


  LoginScreen({this.name});
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final mobileController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  LoginRequestModel requestModel;
  bool isApiCallProcess = false;
  GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  LoginRequestModel loginRequestModel;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    requestModel=new LoginRequestModel();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProgressHUD(
      child: _uiSetup(context),
      inAsyncCall: isApiCallProcess,
      opacity: 0.3,
    );
  }
  Widget _uiSetup(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body:
      Stack(

          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/images/hand.png',),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text("Welcome Doctor! ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold

                      ),),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  ),
                  Text("Let's treat everyone great",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    minLines: 1,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onSaved: (input) => loginRequestModel.Mobile = input,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Enter Mobile No.",
                        hintText: "Enter Mobile No.",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(16.0)))),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: (input) =>
                    loginRequestModel.Password = input,
                    validator: (input) =>
                    input.length < 3
                        ? "Password should be more than 3 characters"
                        : null,
                    minLines: 1,
                    obscureText: true,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Password",
                        hintText: "Password",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(16.0)))),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                    ),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Color(0xFF0769AA),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (validateAndSave()) {
                          print(loginRequestModel.toJson());
                          setState(() {
                            isApiCallProcess = true;
                          });
                          APIService apiService = new APIService();
                          apiService.login(loginRequestModel).then((value) {
                            if (value != null) {
                              setState(() {
                                isApiCallProcess = false;
                              });

                              if (value.Status.isNotEmpty) {
                                final snackBar = SnackBar(
                                    content: Text("Login Successful"));
                                scaffoldKey.currentState
                                    .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                              } else {
                                final snackBar =
                                SnackBar(content: Text(value.Message));
                                scaffoldKey.currentState
                                    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                                    .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                              }
                            }
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text(

                        "Login",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),

                      ),

                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text("Or",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      color: Color(0xFF0769AA),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => LoginOtp("Welcome")),
                                (route) => false);
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Login With OTP",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            // write your function
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (contex) => SplashScreen()));
                          },
                          child: Text(
                              "Forgot Password",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              )
                          )),

                    ],
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [

                    Text(
                      "By logging in or signing up, you agree to the",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Privacy Policy & Terms and Condition",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
            )
          ]),


    );
  }

  bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = globalFormKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Pasting random file from your project doesn't help. There is just bunch of UI stuff unrelated to your issue. Post code that executes your http request and add screenshot from Postman to compare

Comment: Hi, have you tried debugging this issue?...just wanted to understand if the api call is being triggered or not.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).